# How can I get all start datetime and end datetime of all the weeks in a year in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel project I have to be calculating the members commission in each week of a year. Please how do I get the start datetime and end datetime of all the weeks in each year? database used is mysql.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow eliasu. please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. i'm not quite understand your question. do you want to enumereate all 52 weeks start/end date in a year?

Comment: How do you want to handle partial weeks at either end of the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setIsoDate()` sets a carbon date, by year and week. When you got that, you can use `startOfWeek()` and `endOfWeek()` to get the beginning and end of them.

```
$year = 2022;

foreach (range(1, 53) as $week) {
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $date->setISODate($year, $week);

    $date->copy()->startOfWeek()
    $date->copy()->endOfWeek();
}
```